# React-native-Navigation-Stack Version && dependency error

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack, react-native-cli

can somebody help me with the navigation stack dependency error I[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNk6B.png) am very new to react tried so many dependencies but still getting the attached error
[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esiLd.png)

I am attaching your recommended changes [changes I made..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx6LT.png)
then when I[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M3cn.png) tried installing the masked-view it showed me this

Comment: You need to install the stack navigator dependency as well [reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/)

Also for future reference, please wrap code snippets in code blocks vs uploading an image

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the necessary libraries required for react-navigation below are the mentioned npm library you need to install

[image]

Install all the red marked libraries and also do `cd ios` `pod install` and you are good to go.

You only have to install the following libraries

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

for navigation.
Remove `react-navigation/core` , `react-navigation/router` library which you have added extra.

Comment: but its still same ...i downloaded all your recommendation but for @react-native-masked-view is showing the same error

Comment: and i am using windows